# PreInstall script execution failed during installation using packagekmaker

Tags: packagemaker

I have created pkg using packageMaker. It contain preinstall and postnatal script along with other plugin files. when i am trying to install it, its get installation failed message. I did research and find that preinstall scripting is failing this installation.

But when i tried to run preinstall script from terminal. script  is working without any error.

Looking for some help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the log `(Cmd + L)` after the installation fails and see which specific line of your postinstall script failed.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue with my project installer. The installer for me was failing as there was some issue in my script.
In my preinstaller script which was a shell script, I had some command for which the command line argument length was exceeding the permitted length for a shell command.

I am not sure the issue with you is same or not but u can check that or you can change your script from shell to perl in case it is shell.